# How to put avg in descending order?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to get a descending order and round to integer the `zhvi` number of from a csv file using spark.

However, when I try `sort(desc("Zhvi"))` at the end of my code. It always gives me error.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, desc
stateByZhvi = home.select('State','Zhvi').groupBy((col("State"))).avg("Zhvi").show()
```

and part of my result:

```
+-----+------------------+
|State|         avg(Zhvi)|
+-----+------------------+
|   AZ|246687.01298701297|
|   SC|143188.94736842104|
|   LA|159991.74311926606|
|   MN|236449.40239043825|
|   NJ| 367156.5637065637|
|   DC| 586109.5238095238|
|   OR| 306646.3768115942|
|   VA| 282764.4986449864|
```

Any one can help with?

Comment: you do sort(desc("Zhvi")) over the grouped average data. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using SQL:

```
home.createOrReplaceTempView("home")

spark.sql("select State, round(avg(Zhvi)) as avg_Zhvi from home group by State order by 2 desc").show()
```

Comment: Why would anyone revert to SQL if the OP used the DataFrame API and a solution does exist for it?!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, mainly because it's much more convenient for me as for  the ex-DBA. Are there disadvantages? Is DataFrame API more preferrable compared to SQL?

Comment: The only disadvantage is that the OP asked about a non-SQL / DataFrame-based solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
// input dataframe
+-----+------------------+
|State|               avg|
+-----+------------------+
|   AZ|246687.01298701297|
|   SC|143188.94736842104|
|   LA|159991.74311926606|
+-----+------------------+

df.orderBy(desc("avg")).show()

//
+-----+------------------+
|State|               avg|
+-----+------------------+
|   AZ|246687.01298701297|
|   LA|159991.74311926606|
|   SC|143188.94736842104|
+-----+------------------+
```

There might be another issue, it seems you are using "sort(desc("Zhvi"))",

however, the column name changed after the avg function, "|State|         **avg(Zhvi)**|"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the same problem you had, here is my solution. Use agg, avg, alias, and order by (with ascending parameter as false):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
stateByZhvi = home.groupBy((col("State"))).agg.avg(col("Zhvi")).alias("avg_Zhvi").orderBy("avg_Zhvi", ascending=False).select('State','avg_Zhvi')show()
```